# Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, strcat

I'm making a program in which I need to first convert an integer to a string *(char array)* for that I used `itoa()` function which is working fine, after that I want to also concate it to a string, but it's not working and giving me following error:

> **Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)**

**My Code:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *scoreText = "Score: ";
    char *msg;
    int num = 1888;
    itoa(num,msg,10);
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    printf("%s\n", scoreText);
    strcat(scoreText, msg);
    printf("%s\n", scoreText);
}
```

Comment: Where do you expect pointer `msg` points to?

Comment: @Gerhardh I am converting integer to  string using `itoa()` function and then save the result into `msg`

Comment: No, you don't put anything in `msg`. `itoa` tries to put something in the memory where `ptr` **points to**.  Which is unspecified in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0xC0000005` is basically the Windows variant of a segmentation violation (usually caused by trying to use memory you *shouldn't* be using).

One of your problems lies here, with the code:

```
char *msg;
```

This creates a *pointer* to memory but does not actually allocate any memory for the pointer to point to. As it's an object with automatic storage duration, it will contain some arbitrary value, which is likely to be pointing somewhere other than you need.

What you should do instead is something like:

```
char msg[100];
```

which will both allocate 100 bytes for the buffer *and* ensure that the identifier `msg` points to that buffer.

---

Another problem is:

```
char *scoreText = "Score: ";
strcat(scoreText, msg);
```

The first line creates a character pointer and points it at the first character of the string literal `"Score: "`. It is undefined behaviour to attempt to modify string literals (such as by appending a string to them). To fix that issue, you have to have memory that *is* allowed to be modified, such as with:

```
char scoreText[200] = "Score: ";
```

This effectively gives you a 200-byte buffer initially populated with the string (as opposed to a pointer to the string literal), to which you can safely append your (up to) 100-byte `msg` string. It's effectively the same as

```
char scoreText[200];
strcpy(scoreText, "Score: ");
```

---

And, just one final point. You should be aware that `itoa` is *not* standard C but the way you're using it can be easily done with:

```
sprintf(msg, "%d", num);
```

---

Final working code below, though no doubt more improvements could be made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char scoreText[200] = "Score: ";
    char msg[100];
    int num = 1888;
    sprintf(msg, "%d", num);
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    printf("%s\n", scoreText);
    strcat(scoreText, msg);
    printf("%s\n", scoreText);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have applied your code but again I'm getting same error, (I think it's due to fixed `*scoreText`).

Comment: @UsmanDeveloper, that's now also covered in the second part of the answer.

Comment: you are awesome :)

Comment: I have to agree, I ***am*** awesome :-) Just kidding.

Comment: And you can use one `sprintf` to do the strcat too.